# Как расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется такая фраза (думаю, все узнали слова Кота Матроскина из "Простоквашино"): "В такую погоду все свои дома сидят, телевизор смотрят. Только чужие шастают". Так вот, я не уверен, что расставил знаки препинания верно. Мои варианты:
- с запятой ("В такую погоду все свои дома сидят, телевизор смотрят, только чужие шастают");
- с тире ("В такую погоду все свои дома сидят, телевизор смотрят - только чужие шастают");
- и, собственно, с точкой, как я привел в начале.
Какой из этих вариантов правильный?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если текста Успенского нет под рукой, то лучшим вариантом является следующий: "(1)В такую погоду все свои дома сидят, телевизор смотрят. (2)Только чужие шастают".

Парцелляция в предложении (1)  чисто авторская, ее делать необязательно.

Вариант с запятыми не подойдет, так как синтаксис становится нечетким.

Вариант с тире тоже нехорош: первая часть БСП содержит однородные члены и требует перечислительной интонации, а надо еще выразить интонацию бессоюзного предложения, обозначаемую тире. Осуществить это сложно.

Answer (score 1):

У Успенского это вообще три отдельных предложения:

> В такую погоду свои дома сидят. Телевизор смотрят. Только чужие шастают.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, третий вариант, он же первый, не вызывает сомнений относительно соответствия пунктуационным нормам. Каждый человек обладает правом по рождению расчленить предложение точкой на правах его автора как ему заблагорассудится, с тем лишь условием, что первое, базовое предложение обладает смысловой завершенностью. [Убедитесь](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-020.htm#i12810).

Если автор в силу каких-то причин решил своим правом не пользоваться, не в меньшей степени, на мой взгляд, обоснованной является постановка запятой, а затем тире. Последнее предпринимается с целью обозначить противительные отношения между частями бессоюзного предложения. Однако я рекомендую все-таки правом воспользоваться.

Comment: А как вы интонационно выразите однородную связь в первой части предложения и противительные отношения между первой и второй частью?

Comment: Видите ли, я таких тонкостей попросту не чувствую.

Comment: Noir, эти "тонкости" чувствовать не надо, на самом деле они очень просты и их скоро будут проходить в школах, а пока можно отметить следующее. Раньше интонацию в вузах изучали  в разделе "фонетика", а теперь все интонационные термины (пауза, фраза, синтагма, тоническое ударение и пр.) присутствуют в новых учебниках по современному синтаксису. Ну это же совсем другая жизнь!